Estilo para fullcalendar, subrayar día
Estoy utilizando un calendario de fullcalendar para un sistema de turnos, que segun si el dia tiene turnos disponibles o no se pinta de verde o rojo, aqui dejo el codigo:


dayRender: function (date, cell, view) {
                if (date.isBefore(moment(), 'day')) {
                    cell.css('background-color', '#f2f2f2');
                }
                else {
                    if (date.isSame(view.intervalStart, 'month')) {
                        var fechaISO = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        verificarTurnosDisponibles(fechaISO, new Date(date).getDay(), view.intervalStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), view.intervalEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), function (disponible) {                            
                            if (disponible) {
                                cell.css('background-color', '#91cfa4')
                            } else {
                                cell.css('background-color', '#ef7771');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }



Que genera esta vista:

Ahora, yo lo que quiero es que en vez de pintarse la celda, se subraye el numero con ese color

En vez de aplícar el estilo al contenedor del elemento, debes aplicarlo sobre el ancho del elemento que tiene el número o sobre el borde del elemento "celda"

en vez de esto: cell.css('background-color', '#91cfa4'), usa algo así: cell.css({ 'color' : '#91cfa4', 'text-decorarion': 'underline' })...
